# SQL Group BY COLUMN Choose specific rows

Tags: sql

I have been looking for a long time but couldn't find any interesting answers.

Here is my problem, let's say I have a table with 2 columns and multiple rows :

```
column1  |   column2
         |
BKZ-54   |   N/A
BKZ-54   |   OPVE7
BKZ-54   |   OXP5V
ARF-47   |   RB5FR 
ARF-47   |   N/A
ARF-47   |   V7FTS
```

Expected response after SQL Request :

```
column1  |   column2
BKZ-54   |   OPVE7
ARF-47   |   RB5FR
```

Problem is that if I use `GROUP BY column1`, random values of column2 will be chosen and I want to exclude those with `N/A`.

If I use `GROUP BY column1 and WHERE column2 != 'N/A'`, then rows are inexistent in the response.

I want the SQL Request to group by column1 and get a random value corresponding in column2 but different from `'N/A'`.

The only way I see is to make 2 SQL Request but I'm looking for a one time request. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What kind of SQL server are you using? (Microsoft, Oracle, etc)

Comment: Add the row (SKN-69, N/A), and adjust the expected result if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure if you want a truly "random" value, or if any value will do and it just doesn't matter which.  If it's the latter use an aggregate like `MAX()` for choosing the value:

```
SELECT column1, MAX(column2)
FROM yourTable
WHERE column2 <> 'N/A'
GROUP BY column1
```

Comment: I think that is likely an acceptable solution, but they wanted randomness which the MAX would eliminate

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Yeah I question whether they mean random in the true sense or random as in 'any value will do'.  Side note, you have a good solution to true random but I bet they are using MySQL (because OP was able to select multiple columns and group by only one)... We need them to clear some things up for us.

Comment: Thanks, that was just that. I thaught the WHERE statement deleted any column1 where there was a column2 == 'N/A' corresponding but in fact it just choose an other column2 different from 'N/A' associated to column1.

I got confused on phpmyadmin because the filter option on results only filters by page and not on all pages ... that's why I thaught the WHERE statement wasn't doing what I want.

Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server example. You eliminate the 'N/A', but the real trick is to get a top 1 row per Column1 value. I'm accomplishing this by generating row numbers that are partitioned by Column1 and then only accepting where Row=1. NEWID() will cause them to be randomly ordered. Run the inner SELECT statement separately so you can see what it is doing.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (column1 VARCHAR(200),column2 VARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'BKZ-54','N/A'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'BKZ-54','OPVE7'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'BKZ-54','OXP5V'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'ARF-47','RB5FR'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'ARF-47','N/A'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'ARF-47','V7FTS'

SELECT
    Column1,Column2
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY NEWID() ASC) AS [Row]
    FROM @table
    WHERE column2<>'N/A'
) AS OrderedData
WHERE OrderedData.[Row]=1
```